# extends block for HTML is showing up as text rather than actually parsing

Tags: html, css, web

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
```

my index file starts like this but it's not extending base.html it's just showing me my index.html with what I pasted up there as text in my index.html. Im so confused..

I just tried searching solutions but i dont see what else i could change. I'm new to this stuff so only thing it could be is something with the routing but I'm just launching these without app.yaml or main.py files

Comment: yes i have {% endblock content %} at the end

Comment: What system are you using, pre processor/browser/OS etc